# H263 Video RFC Number

Tags: rtp

We are getting RTP Video packet from one TELECOM operator with payload type 96(Dynamic). Audio is AMR format. From H324M negotiation, we know the video is H263. But there are two RFC number for H263. We have send those RTP packets with RTP payload type 34, which shows in wireshark. Now, how we should decide which RFC that TELECOM operator is following?

Exmple RTP header(12 byte) with IUFP (4 byte) = 16 byte:

```
0x80, 0x60, 0xfa, 0x3e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x18, 0xe8, 0xfa, 0x3c, 0x01, 0x00, 0xe0, 0x60,
```

Example packet (in C Array):

packet 1:

```
00 00 89 1A D1 BC F9 19 D0 69 CC 12 3A 7D 6B 3D 30 DA 8C CF 09 2A 73 4E 34 8E 6B AE 7C ED
```

packet 2:

```
00 00 8D 21 B8 82 F4 1C 3F EA DE 12 36 D3 DB DE ED B6 91 C5 A1 DE F0 A5 AD 26 1D 44 AD 4E BC 74 0A 7E 48 9F B4 AF 08 78 AA B5 2E 01 7A A4 18 C0 27 24 76 AF 5B 4D 38 F5 63 DA 23 59 2F 80 C5 93 02 77 A5 FF C4 96 27 B8 34 FF 3A CA 4D 17 BC AD
```

packet 3:

```
00 00 91 1A 14 2E C3 DC 3E 3D 13 9C DB AA C9 39 CC 3A 44 23 E6 11 08 44 A9 AC 53 07 B3 CC B7 53 48 39 31 22 3E DB 6F 5B 2C 31 81 BD 23 D6 8F A7 E0 50 FE C5 C6 52 11 A1 DB C0 21 23 4F 7B C0 8D
```

packet 4:

```
00 00 95 1A B0 7B 10 19 61 EC 44 4E E9 3B 6B 49 EE 91 96 63 13 E1 5F 47 0E D2 92
```

C8 2B 31 0D 68 8E 45 5E 2D 19 13 3E 71 EE 48 AF 7B DD C0 ED

packet 5:

```
00 00 99 18 AE 1D EE 6D 2A 4C 39 3B DE E6 53 7B D4 91 E3 63 4C DF 08 9C 96 3E F7 13 14 8A 9F 36 5F E2 D8 81 E9 B9 F3 C7 DE 8D 27 99 38 B2 4F 48 C4 F7 BC 9A
```

packet 6:

```
00 00 9D 1A 38 77 86 6F 43 CE 3D 22 9C 38 F6 59 34 4D 78 4C BA 7F 3E 75 10 99 F0 CC 33 5C 2D 59 0A 85 FF 8D A5 96 0E 06 6B 6F 44 93 DE F0 CD 09 09 09 09 FD FD 8D E0 1D
```

packet 7:

```
00 00 A1 1B 02 1F 2C 36 2A 36 F7 26 E7 9F 5E 19 AA D7 F1 D4 FA 52 61 9D 3E 6D 2E F0 CD E8 CD 58 BA 7E 0C 7E C4 0B 49 59 5A F7 A8 A7 0F 23 6D EF 7A 9B FA 78 BC
```

Sometimes over network, we are getting clear video, sometimes hazy what we need to solve.